# Extending registration FOSUserBundle form looking for improper methods

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and I extended the registration form to input the name of a company when registering a new user. `Company` is a separate Entity. I created all required methods for the relation handling.

```
/**
 * User entity
 */
class User {
    // ...
    addCompany() { /* ... */ }
    removeCompany() { /* ... */ }
    getCompanies() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I followed the [Symfony guide to embed a Single Object to a form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object):

```
class RegistrationFormType extends \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('...')
            ->add('company', new CompanyType());
    }
    // ...
}
```

The registration form is rendered properly; it shows a field for the Company name. But when I submit, I get

> Neither the property "company" nor one of the methods "setCompany()", "_*set()" or "*_call()" exist and have public access in class "Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User".

I obviously neither don't have a `company` property nor a `setCompany()` method, because it's a manyToMany relationship, thus I have a `companies` property and a `addCompany()` method instead.

Questions

- Why doesn't Symfony also look for a `addCompany()` method?
- Should I implement a `setCompany()` method (e.g. by simply renaming accordingly, or as a wrapper method which calls `addCompany()`)?
- Or is this due to the singular/plural problem which comes up when singular and plural method names can't be interpreted correctly by Symfony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is the [`by_reference`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference) option.

**There are 2 cases:**

1. `by_reference => true` and therefore the setters are called (by default).
2. `by_reference => false` and therefore the adders are called.

What you're trying to do is exactly this :

[How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

---

### Edit 1: The OP wishes to user adders instead of setters

Try this:

```
$builder->add('company', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => new CompanyType(),
    'options'  => array(
        'by_reference'  => false,
    ),
));
```

---

### Edit 2: The OP wishes to create only one company per user

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function whateverAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $company = new Company();
        $user->getCompany()->add($company);

        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // form processing
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeUserBundle:User:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 3: The OP only wants to override the FOSUserBundle form type

You still have the option to create a setter in your entity to solve your issue.

```
/**
 * Set Category
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection $category
 */
public function setCategory($category) {

    $this->category->clear();

    foreach ($category as $cat) {
        $this->addCategory($cat);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

***Note:*** It would be a better practice to use $categories instead of $category if you have a **OneToMany** so that you know that it's a collection. You would have in your entity:

- $companies
- getCompanies()
- setCompanies($companies)
- addCompany($company)
- removeCompany($company)

Comment: ... but does not lead to the wanted result: When I change the last row of my form builder to `->add('company', new CompanyType(), array('by_reference' => false))` it says *Argument 1 passed ... must be an instance of Company, string given*.

Comment: Sadly no: Now the input field for the company name disappeared.

Comment: This is normal: read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage) (as you can see, In both cases, no input fields would render unless your company data array already contained some companies.) Set `'allow_add'    => true` and read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), that's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Still same behaviour: Input field not appearing. I have created a gist so that you can see both files. https://gist.github.com/dialogik/ffa46185785c65528d30

Comment: Again.....no input fields would render unless your company data array already contained some companies. To allow the creation of new companies, you NEED to use prototypes, please read the section on [allowing new tags with the prototype](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype). As I said, it's exactly what you want to do: letting the user add as many companies as he wants.

Comment: This starts to look like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. I only want the user to enter **one** company name (just one, not multiple) and to call the `addCompany()` method accordingly and to persist the company into the db...

Comment: In that case, just create a new empty company field before rendering the form. `$company = new Company();` and before rendering the form, `$user->addCompany($company)`. In that case, you don't need to use prototype, you just create the company field before.

Comment: Ok @GottliebNotschnabel, see my edit, and let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: This does not suit to my specific problem because I have to extend the FOSUserBundle registration form, I don't move on a greenfield. I'll +1 your answer because I really appreciate your effort and help. But I won't accept it yet, so that I can still hope for a suiting answer. Thanks a lot anyway buddy!

Comment: Of course, you still have the option to create a setter in your entity . But from your question, I thought you wanted to avoid that. I mean, you can it's a good practice, I personally do it in all my projects (see my edit3). You would have to create a  setter in the entity, and keep `'by_reference'  => true` in your form type.